# Is the feature to view interesting new questions on other sites discontinued?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, architecture

Until a few days ago when the top bar was redesigned, there was a useful feature to quickly view interesting new questions on the other SE sites. It provided (at least for me) a good opportunity to raise my interest in the other stackexchange sites.

Is this feature removed, or just harder to access?

Comment: Not REmoved, just moved to a more suitable location.